Prove the total variation of a measure equals $\sup \{ \int_{A} f d\nu \; : \; f \in C_{c}(A) \text{ , } |f| \leq 1 \}$ for $A$ open
I am having difficulty solving an exercise in the book "Modern Real Analysis" by Ziemer.
It is exercise 4 of section 6 on signed measures in the chapter on integration (chapter 6).
The exercise statement is :

Show that the total variation of the measure $\nu$ satisfies :
\begin{equation}
\Vert \nu \Vert (A) = \sup \left| \int_{A} f d\nu \; : \;  f \in C_{c}(A) \text{ , } |f| \leq 1 \right|
\end{equation}
for each open set $A$.

I believe that it is assumed here that $\nu$ is a positive measure and $f : A \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ (where $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is the extended real line). The measure space is $(X,\mathcal{M},\nu)$. I believe the measurable sets for the co-domain of $f$ are the Borel sets of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ denoted as $\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$.
I know that since $\nu$ is positive
\begin{equation}
\Vert \nu \Vert(E) = \nu^{+}(E) - \nu^{-}(E) = \nu(E)
\end{equation}
I assume there is a topology defined on $X$, say $(X,\mathcal{T})$ where $\mathcal{T}$
is the set of open sets. I also assume that $C_{c}(A) \subset \overline{\mathbb{R}}^{A}$ is the set of continuous functions defined on the relative topology on $A$ that have compact support. The definition I'm using for the support of $f$ is $\overline{ \{x \in A \mid f(x) \neq 0 \} }$, where $\overline{G}$ is the closure of $G$. Let
\begin{equation}
W = \{ f \in C_{c}(A) \; : \; |f| \leq 1 \} 
\end{equation}
I can see that if $\hat{f} \in W$ and $\hat{f} \equiv 1$ and $A$ is compact that $\sup_{f \in W} \int_{A} f d\nu$ would equal $\Vert \nu \Vert(A)$. But we cannot assume that $A$ is compact.
I've tried to find a way to construct a sequence of functions
$\{ f_{i} \}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that each $f_{i} \in W$ and $f_{i} \rightarrow \hat{f}$. I have not been able to construct a sequence such that each $f_{i}$ has compact support, each $f_{i}$ is continuous, and that the overall sequence converges to $\hat{f}$.
Does such a sequence exist ? I'm not sure what the right approach would be to solve the exercise. Can someone help provide more direction ?

Why are you assuming that $\nu$ is a positive measure?

What do you mean by $\hat{f}$? What does the "hat" over $f$ mean?

In the book they use "measure" to refer to a positive measure and "signed measure" to refer to a signed measure. Signed measures are introduced in this chapter, prior to this chapter all the measures are positive (nonnegative). I'm just using the hat to refer to a specific element that might exist in $W$ as $f$ is the symbol used elsewhere to refer to an arbitrary element of $W$. In the problem statement they say "measure" instead of "signed measure".

What do you know about the topology of $X$?

The problem doesn't specify anything about the topology.  I only know that they say $A$ is open and each $f \in W$ is in $C_{c}(A)$. From this I assume there is some topology defined on $X$.

Without any information about the topology, you cannot prove the result.
